# Can I prevent people from liking pictures on my business page?

Tags: facebook

I would like to share images on fbook with people that I don't want able to contact each other. Is there a setting that will prevent anyone that is liking a business page to be able to "like" posted pictures?

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent someone from liking a picture. It's part of Facebook's structure. If you have a business page and post pictures, people are going to be able to contact each other.